# Parameters OpenGL to SKShader

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit

Is it possible to add parameters OpenGL to SKShader? I need to have a repeating texture in SKShader.

```
 glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
 glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
```

Comment: did you find the solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some extra work and write your own custom shader. Please go to this [blog](http://www.modejong.com/blog/post20_spritekit_repeat_shader/), where different possibilities are discussed, but be careful with the differences between Metal and OpenGL devices. You may get different results.